# TypeError: 'Conv2dLayer' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow to reconstruct a CNN model called 'Deep Voxel Flow': https://github.com/liuziwei7/voxel-flow.

The output of the model is a tensor with the shape of [16,256,256,3] (16 is the batch size, 256 is the size of feature map, and 3 is the number of channels). When I tried to extract first 2 channels from the 4D tensor('flow=deconv4[:, :, :, 0:2]'), but I got an error: 'TypeError: 'Conv2dLayer' object is not subscriptable'.

```
deconv4 = Conv2d(deconv3_bn_relu, 3, [5, 5], act=tf.tanh, padding='SAME', 
W_init=w_init, name='deconv4')

flow = deconv4[:, :, :, 0:2]
```

The expected result is that the 'flow' is a 4D tensor with the shape of [16,256,256,2].

Comment: I used the PyCharm to debug the code, it shown that the shape of 'deconv4' was [16,256,256,3], however, it still got error message when extracting first 2 channels from 'deconv4'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the use of `Conv2D` by a convolution layer, that returns a tensor:

```
deconv4 = tf.layers.conv2d(deconv3_bn_relu, 3, [5, 5], activation=tf.tanh, 
                           padding='SAME', kernel_initializer=w_init,
                           name='deconv4')
```

Then, you cannot use the `[]` to access the result of a Tensorflow operation directly.
But you can use other operations to reshape/modify/split/truncate..etc the tensor.

In your case I think what you're looking for might be:

`flow = tf.slice(deconv4, [0,0,0,0], [16, 256, 256, 2])`

Comment: Hi Tezirg, thanks for your help. I tried to use your answer in my code, however, it still got error: 'TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorlayer.layers.Conv2dLayer'> to Tensor. Contents:   Last layer is: Conv2dLayer. Consider casting elements to a supported type.' Do you have any idea about this? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah , try `.output` member as in `deconv4.output`

Comment: @DeeMa Actually that's because yo're not using a layer but the Conv2D class directly. See my edited answer

Comment: Hi Tezirg, Many thanks for your kind help! The problem has been solved when using '.outputs' in 'deconv4.outputs'. May I ask should I always use the Conv2d Layer to realise convolution rather than using 'def Conv2d'?

Comment: You're very welcome, please consider accepting the answer if it solved you issue. You can you whatever you want as long at it works. I personally prefer using layers because its less code